# How would I join an imported road from OSM to the terrain?

Tags: mesh, add-on

I am new to Blender (and very impressed).

I have imported a terrain, 3D buildings and roads into Blender using the OpenStreetMap add-on.

- The roads are elevated well over the terrain and offset in position.
- If z is the altitude, I would like to zero z so that the roads rest on the terrain.
- The roads are off in x and y as well. The roads run off the terrain and pass over and directly through buildings.
- The default Blender mesh would essentially be underground.

[image]

[image]

Ideally, I would like to be able to apply actual distances to the Blender model in imperial or SI units and if possible include a light grid throughout a volumetric model.

A possible workflow might be:

1. Use OpenStreetMap add-on to import an approximate rendering of the location of interest.
2. Correct placement of roads and buildings.
3. Apply a scale to the scene in units of miles, kilometers, etc.

I am currently researching 2 and 3.

**Blend file:**

[image]

Comment: I don't see here anything particularly unusual. Select All and Move (G) vertices along selected Axis (press X, Y or Z).

Comment: Hi Luke - the roads are about 100 feet above the terrain and some pass directly over buildings. The roads also continue running past the end of the terrain.

Comment: The blender-osm addon places the roads automatically on the terrain. By the way the addon is free now. Get it at https://gumroad.com/l/blender-osm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview:

[image: overview]

1. Change **Clipping** to some really high value to see whole thing at once.
2. Go to **Object Mode**.
3. With still selected roads, go to **Modifier tab** and remove **Boolean**.
4. Change **Shrinkwrap** to **Nearest Surface Point** and mark **Keep Above Surface**.

Comment: Stellar!  Thanks very much for your help!